# Actionscript 3 On Web

Tags: php, actionscript-3, oop, dom

I have a flash actionscript 3 project that works perfectly fine when i run the SWF locally. It also works in MAMP (my localhost development) but doesn't do anything online. Do i need to declare the swf in the document class somehwere.

I'm pulling my hair out. Any ideas are much appreciated.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your online version into firefox, and run firebug. Within firefox, view the "Net" panel, and if there are any files that are failing to load, they will typically show them in red. From there you should be able to determine at least where to look to start troubleshooting this.

Comment: I had my XML file named with camelCase and was calling it with all lowercase. I have a mac I think linux isn't case sensitive and Windows on the remote server is ...Don't quote me on that though.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of reasons for this.. The primary one that comes to mind is if you're loading assets from another domain that doesn't have a cross domain policy (which means it will only work locally).

Provide a link to your uploaded SWF + explain what's not working and I'll be able to help you more.

More info on the above here:

- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html